# Overlapping lines in Gnuplot when exporting

Tags: plot, png, gnuplot, line

I'm trying to plot a discrete brownian path in gnuplot, which involves a lot of overlaping lines. This is how it's displayed in the qt terminal (I have generated the image with a screenshot):

[image: brownian path]

Notice how the overlapping lines get colored in a stronger color, which is beautiful.

If I export it in png, with

```
set term pngcairo size 1366,768 enhanced
```

I obtain this:

[image: brownian path (png)]

All the lines have the same intensity. Setting `transparent` doesn't help, either.

The same happens with this MWE:

```
set term pngcairo size 1366,768 background '#000000' enhanced
set output "image.png"
unset key
set border 0
unset xtics
unset ytics

set samples 1e6
set xrange [0:0.1]
p sin(1/x) w l lw 0.3
set output
```

[image: mwe]

I'm running `gnuplot -d` each time so my local config does not get loaded. How should I export the plot to obtain the same effect as in the GUI?

Comment: How do you get a black background with qt terminal? Is it just a black box behind? I'm trying to replicate your results

Comment: okay, I used `set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb 'black' fillstyle solid noborder`

Comment: @EricDuminil You can also click in the little wrench and modify the background for all the plots you do from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some results of my investigation :

- I couldn't achieve beautiful results with pngcairo either. Opacity isn't added when 2 curves overlap each other.
- Exporting to SVG and converting to PNG looked a bit better, either with `inkscape -z -e image.png -w 1600 -h 1200 image.svg` or `convert -density 3000 -resize 1600x1200 image.svg image.png`. This step could be included in gnuplot as a `system` command.
- It is possible to export the qt render to png directly from the qt window. First menu icon on the left → Export to image
- This process could in theory be automated directly from Gnuplot, without user interaction. A patch has been submitted : https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/665/. As far as I can tell, it hasn't been yet integrated into Gnuplot 5.0.x
- Here is a related discussion on [Gnuplot-dev](http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/Proposal-Saving-graphs-from-Qt-and-wxt-terminals-td18874.html).
- If you feel adventurous, you could try to recompile Gnuplot with the applied patch. The [submitter](https://sourceforge.net/u/lodewyck/profile/) might be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the bounty! It's always a pleasure to dive into gnuplot and spend a few hours trying to get the best results.

Answer (score 1):

Very offtopic in this question, but as a workaround I have made a `Julia` script that replicates the image feeling that I am looking for. I will post it here in case anybody finds it useful.

```
using Images

function paint(Ny, Nx, iters=1e6; stepsize = 50)
    randstep() = rand([-1;1])
    x = Nx÷2
    y = Ny÷2
    M = zeros(Nx,Ny)
    for i in 1:iters
        rx = randstep()
        ry = randstep()
        for i in 1:stepsize
            x = mod1(x+rx, Nx)
            y = mod1(y+ry, Ny)
            M[x,y] += 1
        end
    end
    clamped = M/maximum(M)
    img = [Colors.RGB(0,mm,0) for mm in clamped]
end

img = convert(Image,paint(1366,768,1e4,stepsize=10))

save("coolbrownianwalk.png", img)
```

This produces images like this:

[image: Not really a brownian walk but cool as hell]